# libjpeg installation- how to go through the instruction

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, installation, data-conversion, libjpeg

I have a problem with libjpeg installation.I need it so as to use CImg library and have posibility to save .jpg files.
 I have download file from:
http://www.ijg.org/ and go step by step with instruction( I use VS2015).
Unfortunately I cannot go through first point:

> 1. Open the command prompt, change to the main directory and execute the    command line  NMAKE /f makefile.vc  setup-v10

I got an error in command prompt: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouZaD.png)

> fatal error U1025:file 'makefile.vc' not found

Could you please tell me what's going wrong? Or maybe you know some easiest way to install this library?

Comment: ***Could you please tell me what's going wrong?*** There is no `makefile.vc` file in the current folder. Looking at the download this file exists in the `jpeg-9b` folder so you had your cmd.exe in the wrong folder when you ran that command. Your linked image shows that you were in the program files folder.

Comment: Did you go into the `jpeg-9b` subdirectory of downloaded sources?

Comment: In the command prompt, type `cd /d <path to libjpeg files>`, e. g. `cd /d c:\jpeg-9b` or whatever the path is where you extracted the files. Then call `NMAKE /f makefile.vc setup-v10` which should now be able to find the `makefile.vc` in the current directory. To verify that you are in the correct directory you may also enter `dir` and check if `makefile.vc` is listed.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I have chosen wrong folder. Problem solved :)

Comment: @drescherjm, could you please add a reply with your comment and it seems solved Paulina's issue? I will recommend Paulina to mark it and it will help other community members who meet this issue to easier search this information.

Comment: @Paulina, please mark drescherjm's reply as answer, since is solved your issue, it will easy for others to search this useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fatal error

> fatal error U1025:file 'makefile.vc' not found

is caused by `nmake` not finding the file `makefile.vc` in the folder that you executed the command

```
NMAKE /f makefile.vc setup-v10
```

Looking at the source zip file it appears the source is located in the `jpeg-9b` folder.

To solve this problem you need to change directory of your command prompt cmd.exe to the `jpeg-9b` folder before running the nmake command. To do so use the `cd` command in your cmd.exe session. The syntax is

```
cd fullpath
```

where fullpath is the full path where you have the `jpeg-9b` folder. If your path includes spaces make sure to quote the path with double quotes.